# Prickly pear cactus needs help

Tags: diagnosis, cactus

[image]Hi all,

I recently moved into a rental with this mature, potted prickly pear out front. While it didn’t look great at move in, it has definitely gotten worse in the last couple of weeks, with more and more arm drooping (though no pads have fallen off yet).

Based on the appearance I would guess it’s under watered, but we’ve received a healthy amount of rain recently, so perhaps it’s over watered? Or could it be a fungus/pest?

I’m a total newbie here (this site and cactus maintenance generally), and any advice would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have [lignification](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lignification_d%27Opuntia_ficus-indica.jpg) here (become woody), I have read somewhere (don't know where anymore) that it is normal in *Opuntia* cacti.

Comment: Is it located in full sun or shade? Also, can you check the pot to see if it has any drainage holes?